# json conversion using jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs

I am using jar files instead of maven because i dont have internet.

**problem**: i am using jersey implemenation of jax-rs. i need to convert the java to json but it is giving the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/ws/rs/RuntimeType;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:67)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:730)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:648)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureMetaProviders(ResourceConfig.java:829)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:453)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1236)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4910)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5192)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1387)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the code i am using is:

```
package mypack;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.BackgroundScheduler;

import entity.Res;

@Path("/s")
public class webapi {

    @GET
    @Path("q/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Res method(@PathParam("name") String name){
        try{
            Res r = new Res();
            r.setId(5);
            r.setName(name);
            return r;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

the res class is as follow:

```
package entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Res {

    @XmlElement int id;
    @XmlElement String name;
    public Res() {
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

the jar files that i am using are:

[image: image of jar files i have embedded]

web.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>mypack</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

what is the reason for the error?

Comment: This error normally comes because of version mismatch. Please verify whether you are using jersey jars of same version

Comment: Your `jersey-media-moxy-2.3.jar` might be related to your error. Try removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think there may be a problem with the `jar` Versioning . Because the jar that you used for your Project is `Older` Version. Please update your `lib` to update the `jersey` dependency as i see and predict the error.

> I would suggest you to add `jars` atleast of Version `2.7` instead of `2.2` or `2.3` as your dependency Says.

Please Update your `lib` Folder then Clean your Project .

Build Your Project again. After Updating your `lib` with New `jar` Files .

Thank You

Comment: While you may be right about version issues, the questions says in the very beginning that he's not using maven.

Comment: @andrepnh Thanks I have updated my answer as per User Project Structure. Thanks Again.

Comment: Thanks everyone!! But I guess for Jersey media moxy it is the latest version. i. e. 2.3. Please provide me link of latest version if I am wrong

Comment: I have added Jersey media moxy to convert content to json. Also I found a 2.22 version of same but it is giving me noclassdeffounderror